# Java: JDOM2 write ascii character in xml

Tags: java, xml, ascii, jdom-2

i am writing a xml, using `JDOM2`

the customers wish is, to have a line as follows:

```
<VT xml:space="preserve">&#50;&#48;</VT>
```

but all I can create is:

```
<VT xml:space="preserve">20</VT>
```

because the ascii is converted by my format encoding ("`ISO-8859-1`")

how to prevent this element from being converted...?

this is, what i use:

```
String str = "&#50;";
String unescapeXml = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(str);
element.addContent(unescapeXml);
```

also i use:

```
format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
format.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
format.setExpandEmptyElements(true);
XMLOutputter out;
OutputStreamWriter fw = null;

out = new XMLOutputter();
out.setFormat(format);

try {
    fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
    PrintStream printStream = System.out;

    // fw = new FileWriter(file);

    out.output(doc, printStream);
```

Comment: The XML specification indicates that the two formats are identical. There is no difference between them. it is like the difference between 1000mm and 1 meter - except in this case the convention is to use the `2` format instead of `&#50;`. If your customer is insisting on the `&#50;` type format then their systems are not using standard-compliant XML parsers (you should recommend that they use JDOM ;-) )

Comment: @rolfl thank you, this was also, what I was thinking.

Comment: but still, is there any possibillity in jdom-2 to print out the ascii-format?

Answer (score 0):

In JDOM you can establish rules for telling the output formatter when to escape character output. It is highly unconventional, but you could probably build an Escapetrategy like:

```
private static final EscapeStrategy alldigits = new EscapeStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldEscape(char ch) {
        return Character.isDigit(ch) || DefaultEscapeStrategy.shouldEscape(ch);
    }
};
```

The above instance will cause all digits, and any other regularly-escaped characters to be escaped.

You can then set that strategy on an instance of your output formatter:

```
format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
format.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
format.setExpandEmptyElements(true);
format.setEscapeStrategy(alldigits);
```

Read up more about the EscapeStrategy here: http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/EscapeStrategy.html

and the way it is used in JDOM here: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/output/Format.java#L147 and here: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/output/support/AbstractXMLOutputProcessor.java#L765

Comment: thanks again, this causes a lot of trouble throughout the whole xml.

also, this converts a 2 into &#x32; and not my desired &#50;

so this would cause the troubles, to let this happen only locally, delete the x and add 18... :D